# Benefits of using inline assembly for x86 in C?

Tags: x86, inline-assembly

I've done some googling-research on the topic "When to use ASM?" and found some useful information. Of course people mentioned vast areas of application: size and speed optimization of HL code, bootloaders, embedded systems, driver development, reverse engineering etc.

Now, I'd like to ask what can I achieve with ASM that cannot be done (or is highly ineffective) using normal C compiler (say gcc) on Intel processor (x86)?

I've heard about:

- implementing mutexes - direct CPU support needed (eg. `lock`, `xchg`)
- fancy bit operations - find highest/lowest bit set to 1 (`bsf`, `bsr`), test if a bit is 1 (`bt`, `bts`...), rotate a value (`ror`, `rol`)
- interrupt masking (`sti`, `cli`)
- accessing CPU-specific information (`cpuid`)

Some people suggest re-writing standard memory functions (eg. memcpy()) in ASM. I thought that compilers nowadays have already these operations implemented in an optimal manner, but maybe I'm wrong?

Someone also mentioned int/float conversion which I don't understand. I mean is this also much more efficient to perform such a conversion manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143561/is-there-a-need-to-use-assembly-these-days

Comment: Thanks for a link. I've went through that topic, found some answers, but still want some more : )

Answer (score 1):

Using advantage of CPU architectiure that is not supported by compiler.  When your compiler is not good enought to perform `vectorizations` on your calculations to get a better performance, you can use assembly too. Think about doing 32 char calculations with a single instruction in AVX capable CPU.

- Making direct hardware access for device drivers.
- Spot-optimizing speed-critical sections of code.
- Using class-structures and elements of them freely
- Based on arch., [using xmm-ymm registers for push and pop operations of EAX,EBX,...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630571/is-it-safe-to-use-xmm-registers-to-save-the-general-purpose-ones) decreases function overheading.
- Putting a long NOP sequence as editable area(for self-editing)

Comment: Oh, that's someting new and interesting for me. Thanks!